# C++ how to remove duplicates from vector of Class type?

Tags: c++, vector, duplicates

I have a class, the constructor looks like this:

```
myclass(int=0,string="",int=0,string="",int=0,int=0,
        int=0,int=0,string="",int=0,int=0);
```

and a vector with elements of this type

```
vector<myclass>myvect;
```

the vector is sorted and I am trying to remove duplicates
and this is not working:

```
std::vector<myclass>::iterator it;
   it=std::unique (myvect.begin(), myvect.end());   
   myvect.resize(std::distance(myvect.begin(),it) );
```

I get this error

```
:algorithm(1862): error C2678: binary '==' :
 no operator found which takes a left-hand operand 
of type 'myclass' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

any idea why?
is there any way I can remove duplicates from this vector?

Comment: Implement `operator==` for `myclass`?

Comment: A simple solution is to implement your own equality operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `std::unique` algorithm needs to know how to compare two `myclass` objects for equality. There are two ways you can do this. The first is to implement `myclass::operator==`. The second is to pass a binary predicate to `std::unique`:

```
std::unique (myvect.begin(), myvect.end(),
             [](const myclass& a, const myclass& b) {
               return /* some expression to test equality */;
             });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, my the question was wrong I mean how to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You probably didn't implement `myclass::operator==`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to overload the `operator ==` for your class  `myclass` in order to apply the `unique` algorithm.

Quoting from [std::unique](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/unique/) documentation:

> The function uses operator== to compare the pairs of elements (or pred, in version (2)).